# Chrome browser won't run on Debian 12

Tags: debian, chrome

I attempted to install Google's Chrome Browser on Debian 12 with GNOME as follows:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub > 
linux_signing_key.pub
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 linux_signing_key.pub 
/etc/apt/keyrings/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed- 
by=/etc/apt/keyrings/linux_signing_key.pub] 
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sourc>
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

The Chrome icon appeared amongst my other application icons. However, when I click on it, it runs in a circle for a minute or so, then dumps me back into the Debian splash screen with no sign of a browser. Hoping that a second time might be the charm, I removed the installation:

```
sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
```

And tried again with the same result - the whirling dirvish and then the Debian splash screen.

Comment: what is this "Debian splash screen"? Anyway, try running it from the command line, you may get some useful error information. Also, does chromium work?

Comment: @Jaromanda X -- Once again your comments have helped me to solve the problem. I tried it from the command line. It not only worked, but subsequently, so do clicking on the icon in the GUI. Thank you!

In response to your question - In the Gnome desktop for Debian, there is a splotch of wallpaper that covers the screen most of the time. I call it the Debian Splash Screen. If you click the Window key, it reduces in size and reveals what I refer to as the Task Bar.

Comment: oh, yeah - haven't used GNOME in a while, I see what you mean - not sure why running from the command line fixed it though!! Mysteries of Chrome I guess